# Where can I check the transaction usage?

Tags: transactions, here-api

I can check how many requests I sent to the API a few month ago. However, I cannot find that page now. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Usage API to query your usage; a get request set-up with the start and end dates using your org-id similar to below.

```
https://usage.bam.api.here.com/v2/usage/realms/org123456789?startDate=2021-07-01T10:39:51&endDate=2021-08-30T10:39:51
```

For more details see the documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/cost-management/dev_guide/topics/usage-service.html